Jest test - useFormStatus is not a function
On Next.js 14 and have a simple test with useFormStatus hook. It is causing an error
TypeError: (0 , _reactdom.useFormStatus) is not a function
As soon as I remove the useFormStatus, the tests pass.
Source file using useFormStatus:

import { useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

export default function MyComponent(){
    const {pending} = useFormStatus()
    if(pending){
        return null
    }
    return ( <div>some jsx</div>)

}


And the test:
it('renders', () => {
    render(<MyComponent />) //error on render
    expect(1).toBe(1)

})


Should I try to mock useFormStatus? In Next 13 I believe useFormStatus was experimental, but I believe it is now stable.

just try to mock the hook in test file
jest.mock('react-dom', () => ({
useFormStatus: jest.fn()
}));

@VickyDhakar
I'm using the pending status in the source code const { pending } = useFormStatus();
How do I properly mock it in the test - for example this doesn't resolve the error:
jest.mock("react-dom", () => ({ __esModule: true,  useFormStatus: jest.fn(() => { pending: false })),}));

In Next.js 13, the useFormStatus hook was part of the react-dom package, but as of Next.js 14, it seems that it's no longer provided by react-dom.
To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

Mock the useFormStatus hook: If you're only testing MyComponent and you don't need the actual functionality of useFormStatus, mocking it could be a viable option. You can create a mock implementation for it.
jest.mock('react-dom', () => ({
__esModule: true,
useFormStatus: jest.fn(),
}));
This way, you're telling Jest to replace useFormStatus with a mock function, which should eliminate the TypeError during testing.
Use a different hook or approach: If useFormStatus is crucial for your component logic and you need to test it properly, consider whether it's still available in a different package or if there's a replacement hook you can use.


How do you properly mock it with the pending status from useFormStatus ? The above doesn't fix the error

I asked here if you're interested in answering another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78433884/how-to-mock-useformstatus-pending

I was able to make it work at this way:
jest.mock("react-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-dom"),
  useFormStatus: jest.fn(() => ({
    pending: false,
  })),
}));

The main issue with the approach in the main thread comment is that the entire react-dom lib was being overwritten and the test fails when jest and react tries to use its other methods.
